# Russian problem book on Real Analysis, Functional Analysis, Topology, et al.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, optimization, numerical-methods

I am looking for (English translated) Russian problem book similar to "Problems in Mathematical Analysis - Demidovich", but for following topics

- Real Analysis (topics as Measure Theory, Lebesgue Integral, ..)
- Functional Analysis
- Topology
- Numerical Analysis
- Linear Programming

Any suggestions...Thanks.

Comment: A book you can't miss: Makarov's [Selected Problems in Real Analysis](https://www.amazon.com/Selected-Problems-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821845594/). Note that it barely touches on measure theory.

Answer (score 0):

Selected Problems in Real Analysis
(B. M. Makarov, M. G. Goluzina, A.A.Lodkin,andA.N.Podkorytov)

Very good problem book about real analysis,measure theory , Lebesgue integrals